# Solving an equation with one variable in Python

Tags: python, scipy, equation-solving, nonlinear-equation

I am trying to solve the equation: `log(1+x)/x  -  1/(1+x)   ==   2/3 * q * x**2` for `x` with `q = 4e-4`

I tried

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
```

```
q = 4e-4
eqn = lambda x: np.log(1+x) / x  -  1 / (1+x)   -   2/3 * q * x**2 
sol = so.fsolve(eqn, 1)[0]
print(sol)
```

and

```
q = 4e-4
eqn = lambda x: np.log(1+x) / x  -  1 / (1+x)   -   2/3 * q * x**2 
sol = so.root_scalar(eqn, bracket=(1e-6, 1e20)).root
print(sol)
```

but get absurd answers.

I tried plotting the equation as follows:
[image]

I am expecting the answer to be `x ~ 20`. How do I get this?

Comment: Your starting guesses are to the left side of the inflection point, so the solvers go in the wrong direction.  Make your starting guess 3 and it converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These algorithms work best when you provide a good initial guess or a tighter bracket.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, root_scalar, root

def eqn(x): 
    q = 4e-4
    return np.log(1+x)/x - 1/(1+x) - 2/3*q*x**2


sol_fsolve = fsolve(eqn, 10)[0]
sol_rootscalar = root_scalar(eqn, bracket=(1e-6, 100)).root
sol_root = root(eqn, 10).x[0]

print(sol_fsolve)       # 19.84860182482322
print(sol_rootscalar)   # 19.848601824823366
print(sol_root)         # 19.84860182482322
```

Answer (score 1):

just modify the init value of x may help

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so

q = 4e-4
eqn = lambda x: np.log(1+x) / x  -  1 / (1+x)   -   2/3 * q * x**2 
sol = so.fsolve(eqn, [15])[0]
print(sol)
```

will output

```
19.848601824823362
```